# How To log activity for anonymous user in heartbeat activity?

Tags: heartbeat, users

I am using [anonymous publishing](https://www.drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing) module and [heartbeat](https://www.drupal.org/project/heartbeat) activity module. I want to log activity for content posted as anonymous to be logged in heartbeat activity
How can I achieve it? I checked in the database and could see that no activity was logged in
 heartbeat table

Comment: There are currently [5 open](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/heartbeat?text=anonymous&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All) issues for heartbeat and anonymous, and [a lot](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/heartbeat?text=anonymous) of issues was created in the past. Have you checked if your issue isn't a duplicate of one of them? *Note that search links to Drupal.org may not work if you are not logged in.*

Comment: thanks @Molot for the link but the issue does not have relation with the above post. So I thought there may be an approach to allow anonymous user's activity to be logged in heartbeat

Comment: There is [at least one issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1591564) suggesting the exact opposite is true and anonymous activity is shown even if administrator does not want it to.

Comment: thanks again @Molot but I also know there is some way that heartbeat activity logs the anonymous users content and I would like to know how can I achieve the same. (Nowadays no one seems to answer) ..

Comment: Sorry. I never used heartbeat on sites I allowed anon activity. Never used it on anything serious, to be honest. Good luck, and consider opening support request in issue queue.